# expo-ads-admob make app crash after build

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

Please provide the following:
1. SDK Version:36
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all):Android

ads working good on expo but after build, went i play reward ads, it make app crash, please check this video for more detail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKT6ecCR55s

```
            AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID('my-id');
            await AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync();
            await AdMobRewarded.showAdAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import

> setTestDeviceIDAsync

like this : `import { AdMobRewarded, setTestDeviceIDAsync } from 'expo-ads-admob'`

and use it, in useEffect or componentDidMount like this : `setTestDeviceIDAsync('EMULATOR')`

Comment: Thanks, my problem is resovle but you give me an awsome tip for next time

Comment: Do we need to add this even when the app is in production? I am facing the same issue